# how to load pdf viewer from html2pdf on javafx WebView

Tags: java, jquery-plugins, html2pdf, javafx-webengine

```
WebView view = new WebView();
final WebEngine eng = view.getEngine();
eng.load("http://localhost/system-eoq/report.php");
```

I try to load my web page on JavaFX WebView. Everything is fine but a problem is on pdf viewer it doesn't work on JavaFX WebView this is my web look like.
[image]

Comment: It might be caused by the limitations of the used userAgent (Which can be retrieved with `webEngine.getUserAgent()`). If you know a useragent which does function as required, than you could set it prior of showing/loading a webPage (javafx8+ only feature).