# Downlad PDF from PDF Viewer using Selenium/Python/Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pdf, web-scraping

I try to navigate through a webpage and whenever a pdf viewer appears, I want to download the pdf file. So to keep it easy in the beginning, I only try to login to the page, navigate to the first page that holds a pdf and try to download it.

The code I used so far:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "/Users/XXX/Documents", 
"download.prompt_for_download": False, 
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True 
})

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/XXX/Documents/chromedriver", options=options)
browser.get('the login webpage')
```

From here I login and navigate to the desired webpage.
And from then on, I don't really know how to get the PDF...
Hope someone can help me out here.

Thank you

Comment: Is the pdf a clickable link that opens up?

Comment: no. the webpage actually displays the PDF-Viewer

Comment: like here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940387/how-to-load-pdf-viewer-from-html2pdf-on-javafx-webview)

Comment: for Firefox, `driver.get('about:reader?url='+url)` shows the pdf viewer. the syntax should be similar in chrome

Comment: and how will that help me to download the file?

Comment: maybe you can print the file afterwards in pdf by clicking the windows

Comment: What does the HTML look like for the in-page PDF viewer?  - Open up devtools, and inspect it. You might notice that the URL for the pdf is in the source.... From that you can navigate your current or a new window.

Comment: No there is no URL in the source...

Comment: ok you might be satisfied with the results of the software named wkhtmltopdf. this works fine with pdfkit